# Using Mediainfo in Bash with multiple hard drives

Tags: bash, hard-drive, mediainfo

I am using mediainfo in a bash script to compile and spit out some info into a .csv. I have two separate hard drives on the mac I am using and I usually run the script on the main hard drive with everything on it. I recently ran out of room and am now needing to run the script on folders in my second internal hard drive. When it gets to the mediainfo portion of the script it waits and waits and does nothing. It never errors out and looks like it is running (for hours) but I get no result.

Do I need to copy mediainfo to the second drive?

It also did the same when I tried to run the script on a folder within an external hard drive. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for what do you need a copy of `mediainfo` on the second drive? If the drive is cnnected to a pc, and used by system, it shall be seen to system, and its programs. So you just try to use the `mediainfo` app for the second drive etc.

Also try to use `df` in [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal), it will show you drives used in system along with free-space:

```
df
```